# How do I post a parameter as XML string using Postman

Tags: xml, post, postman

I want to post xml to a webservice using postman.
Below is the raw body xml. 
The parameter "xml" is a string value that I'd like to pass through, however, the request status returns 400 due to bad syntax. I suspect that its because the parameter value is being formatted as xml.

Everything works fine in my real applications, I just cannot get this to work if I want to test using postman.

How can one send this parameter as string?

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
  <SaveLead xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <xml>
     <enquiry><Lead Ref='1234' Source='SourceDesc'><Contact FirstName='TestN' Surname='TestS' Email='testn@test.co.za' Mobile='0830000000' /></Lead></enquiry>
    </xml>
  </SaveLead>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

A sample of the webservice soap request

```
POST /webservice1.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxxx
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/SaveLead"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<SaveLead xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <xml>string</xml>
</SaveLead>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: What headers are you using? Have you tried `text/xml`?

Comment: @DannyDainton Yeah I am using Content-Type: text/xml

Comment: I'm not sure of the implantation details of the webservice so it's difficult to offer more help without more information in the question. I hate to say this (because it's horrible) but have you tried SOAPUI to do this?

Comment: @DannyDainton I just tried SoapUI and it's giving the same issue. Back to using Postman; If I replace the <xml> parameter with just a normal string like "test", the request works fine. So the parameters XML elements are causing the issue. Is there any way of converting it to a string so it does not interpret the parameter value as actual XML tags? Apologies, trying to explain as best I can.

Comment: Have you looked into using something like CDATA https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect in the request maybe? It not something i know a great deal about to be honest.

Comment: @DannyDainton that worked, thank you very much :)

Comment: If I add that as an answer do you want to accept it?

Comment: @DannyDainton Oops, I just posted the answer. If you post the answer I'll accept yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per Danny's comment above, escaping the XML string with the CDATA section solved this.

> Definition: CDATA sections may occur anywhere character data may occur; they are used to escape blocks of text containing characters which would otherwise be recognized as markup. CDATA sections begin with the string `<![CDATA[ " and end with the string " ]]>`

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
  <SaveLead xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <xml>
    <![CDATA[  <enquiry><Lead Ref='1234' Source='SourceDesc'><Contact FirstName='TestN' Surname='TestS' Email='testn@test.co.za' Mobile='0830000000' /></Lead></enquiry> ]]> 
    </xml>
  </SaveLead>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please accept your answer, I only pointed you in the right direction. :)